# How to create and attach a normal cookie to a response by tipfy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

Hi um having a problem of create a cookie [not secured] by using tipfy . The tipfy class

```
class SessionStore(object):
#: A dictionary with the default supported backends.
default_backends = {
    'securecookie': SecureCookieSession,
}
```

implements the securecookie and i cannot use this implementation for creating a cookie to work in http handlers. Can any one give me a solution for this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the docs for Tipfy, securecookie seems to only mean that the cookie is validated to not have been altered client-side and nothing to do with HTTP vs HTTPS:

> Secure cookies are cookies that are not alterable from the client side because they add a checksum that is validated in the server when read

Take a look at the docs here for more info: http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/session/